# Windows 7 installation without keyboard+mouse?

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, keyboard, mouse

What I have:
I'm setting up a brand new computer. It came with Windows 10 preinstalled, but I've unplugged that disk and I am now installing Windows 7 on a separate disk instead. Standard USB keyboard+mouse is provided with the computer. The computer only has USB+audio+LAN+HDMI connections, nothing else.

What I did:
- I installed the blank disk and booted from the Windows 7 installer DVD.
- The installer did its thing and rebooted into the **first boot** setup.

**Problem:**
**The keyboard+mouse are not active, so I can't do anything at all.** Without any input devices, I can't complete the installation, nor can I add additional drivers.

What I've tried:
- I know that the input devices work on this computer: it's fine when I boot Windows 10, and it was fine during the first part of the Windows 7 installation too.
- I tried a Logitech Unifying Receiver linked to keyboard+mouse, but this also didn't work.
- I tried booting into Safe Mode but it won't let me until the **first boot** has taken place.
- I've double-checked the BIOS settings but there's nothing there that looks related.
- I've plugged the input devices into USB 2.0 ports, and USB 3.0 ports. Made no difference.

I could try to wipe the disk and install Windows 7 again, though I highly doubt that will change anything. It seems that there is a problem with the Windows 7's USB hub drivers, rather than with the peripherals themselves. It looks like [xHCI is the problem according to this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1254702/9350) but I don't have any USB-hub expansion card to test with.

Am I stuck, or is there a solution??

Comment: This will be related to the Windows 7 meida/installer not having your USB (I'll presume 3.0) controller drivers...  the only solution I know of is to either find/buy a PCI USB 2.0 card or re-create your Windows 7 media using DISM to inject USB 3.0 drivers into the WIM image that makes up the installer... See guided walkthrough of DISM/WIM injection: http://codeabitwiser.com/2014/03/how-to-install-windows-7-with-only-usb-3-0-ports/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to the fact Windows 7 didn't ship with many (if any at all) USB 3.0 drivers.

There are very few solutions to this:

1. Install a PCI card that has USB 2.0  - even then, it may not pick up the PCI card... it should, though.
2. Inject your USB 3.0 drivers (typically the USB hub/controller) into your Windows 7 media using DISM on another computer.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue. Windows isn't installed. Bios recognised the kb/ms but as soon as the Windows install options came up nothing works and the dongle is definitely in a 2.0 port